# Getting error while trying to set AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL : )

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

PlayerAudio[52707:3765595] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id 
getting this error before playing audioPlayer.Play()

Answer (score 1):

This is an console message which is not affecting the working of audio player.

Comment: Seemed to just be a problem when using the simulator... still no sound on my real iOS device though.